# Fail to access/cast time.Time

Tags: go, casting

When using  the https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira:

The issue - Resolution Date is defined as

```
struct {
  ...
  Resolutiondate                Time              `json:"resolutiondate,omitempty" structs:"resolutiondate,omitempty"`
  ...
}
```

and

```
type Time time.Time
```

Attempting to access use github.com/spf13/cast

```
var resDate time.Time
resDate, err = cast.ToTimeE(issue.Fields.Resolutiondate)
```

I get:

```
err = "unable to cast jira.Time{wall:0x0, ext:63694019156, loc:(*time.Location)(0xe10a80)} of type jira.Time to Time"
```

or when attmpting to cast, I get a cast violation

```
resDate = issue.Fields.Resolutiondate.(time.Time)
```

(tried to change type of Resolutiondate to time.Time, but got a html response cast error...)

Comment: Based on your description, you should be able to do `resDate=time.Time(issue.Fields.ResolutionDate)`

Comment: Go does not have a type cast feature like other languages. Use the [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) described in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so sure that I tested: resDate=time.Time(issue.Fields.ResolutionDate)
Thanks for the help